# QML Row element refuses to work

Tags: qml, qtquick2

I know I should be using Row, Column etc. rather than items anchored by ID to make my code simpler and easier to read. But they refuse to work most of the time. For example, in this case:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ListView {
    id: listView
    anchors.fill: parent
    topMargin: spacing
    anchors.leftMargin: spacing
    anchors.rightMargin: spacing
    clip: true
    spacing: 0.5 * pxPermm

    model: SqlQueryModel {}
    delegate: Rectangle {
        id: delegateItem
        color: "white"
        height: 14 * pxPermm
        width: listView.width
        clip: true
        Row {
            id: row
            anchors.fill: delegateItem
            spacing: pxPermm
            Image {
                height: row.height
                width: height
                source: "qrc:/resources/ryba.jpg"
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
            }
            Item {
                id: textItem
                height: row.height
                Label {
                    anchors.left: textItem.left
                    anchors.top: textItem.top
                    text: nazov
                    font.bold: true
                }
                Label {
                    anchors.left: textItem.left
                    anchors.bottom: textItem.bottom
                    text: cas
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This shows two Labels on the top of an Image in the delegate of list view. Not two labels to the right of the image, as you would expect. However, this code works:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ListView {
    id: listView
    anchors.fill: parent
    topMargin: spacing
    anchors.leftMargin: spacing
    anchors.rightMargin: spacing
    clip: true
    spacing: 0.5 * pxPermm

    model: SqlQueryModel {}
    delegate: Rectangle {
        id: delegateItem
        color: "white"
        height: 14 * pxPermm
        width: listView.width
        clip: true
        Row {
            id: row
            anchors.fill: delegateItem
            spacing: pxPermm
            Image {
                height: row.height
                width: height
                source: "qrc:/resources/ryba.jpg"
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
            }
            Label {
                text: nazov
                font.bold: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course I need to show more than one label in the delegate. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried changing to RowLayout/ColumnLayout? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-rowlayout.html

Comment: Yes, but with RowLayout the image is stretched to fill the whole delegate :-( But I have found the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that Item has zero width by default. The code works properly after the width is set:

```
            Item {
                id: textItem
                height: row.height
                width: childrenRect.width
                // labels etc
            }
```